# Adobe AIR - control scanner

Tags: api, air, adobe

I want to ask you if there is any solution how to scan documents natively using Adobe AIR. I have heard that it can be achieved using NativeProcess API but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NativeProcess simply allows you to control other applications via the command line.

I found references to people executing JAR files that are able to communicate directly with hardware devices, but you need to first find some executable that is capable of communicating with a scanner before you can think about how to handle what that application returns with AIR.